# 'chromium-browser' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python-3.x, aiml

I have used this code in AIML file

```
<category>
      <pattern>OPEN GOOGLE</pattern>
      <template>
           <random>
             <li>Sure thing! </li>
             <li>Right away, sir! </li>
             <li>On it! </li>
          </random>
          <system> chromium-browser "http://www.google.com"</system>
      </template>
  </category>
```

but i am getting the error that chromium-browser is not an external command.

P.S- I am running it with Python 3.7

Answer (score 0):

if you are on mac download chrome and try this

`<system> open -a "Google Chrome" http://google.com</system>`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your interpreter supports AIML 2, you can do this using the <link> tag.

```
<category>
    <pattern>OPEN GOOGLE</pattern>
    <template>
        <link>
            <text>
                <random>
                    <li>Sure thing!</li>
                    <li>Right away, sir!</li>
                    <li>On it!</li>
                </random>
            </text>
            <url>http://www.google.com</url>
         </link>
    </template>
</category>
```